# how to grab the payload inside of withlatestfrom with ngrx?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

hi i have the following code where the selector requires an index to grab a value from the store, I use withLatestFrom to grab this value from the store only the selector requires a value from the payload
which is only available inside of `switchmap` with `ac`
but is there some other rxjs method we can use to grab this value from the action so that we can use it inside of `withLatestFrom`

```
  fetchYour = createEffect(() => {
    return this.actions.pipe(
      ofType(rdxMainWalletProtectYourBurnFetch),
      withLatestFrom(this.store.select(getTokenToken), this.store.select(getMainWalletProtectYourProbationem(ac??.index))),
      switchMap(ac => aschax.post('/api/transfer/burn', ac[0].payload!).then(res => {
        return {
          type: RDX_MAIN_WALLET_PROTECT_YOUR_BURN_FETCH_SUCCESS,
          payload: res.data,
          component: ac[0].component
        }
      }).catch((err: AxiosError) => {
        return {
          type: RDX_MAIN_WALLET_PROTECT_YOUR_BURN_FETCH_ERROR,
          payload: err.response?.data,
          component: ac[0].component
        }
      }))
    )
  })
```

at the place of the question marks i need to grab the index from the action his payload
down below you can find the selector

```
export const getMainWalletProtectOtherProbationem = (ischin: number) => createSelector(
  getMainWalletProtectFeatureState,
  state => state.otherBids.getIn([ischin, 'probationem'])
)
```

Comment: I would try to add a `map` operator right after the `ofType` to retreive the action props.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `concatLatestFrom` from ngrx instead of `withLatestFrom`.

https://ngrx.io/api/effects/concatLatestFrom

https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/main/docs/rules/prefer-concat-latest-from.md

```
this.actions$.pipe(
 concatLatestFrom(() => this.store.select(fromCustomers.selectActiveCustomer))
)
```